# Bash script comparison in combination with getfattr

Tags: bash

I am currently stuck with a problem in my Bash script and seem to run even deeper in the dark with every attempt of trying to fix it.

Background:
We have a folder which is getting filled with numbered crash folders, which get filled with crash files. Someone is exporting a list of these folders on a daily basis. During that export, the numbered crash folders get an attribute "user.exported=1".

Some of them do not get exported, so they will not have the attribute and these should be deleted only if they are older than 30 days.

My problem:
I am setting up a bash script, which is being run via Cron in the end to check on a regular basis for folders, which have the attribute "user.exported=1" and are older than 14 days and deletes them via `rm -rfv FOLDER >> deleted.log`

We however also have folders which do not have or get the attribute "user.exported=1" which then need to be deleted after they are older than 30 days. I created an IF ELIF FI comparison to check for that but that is where I got stuck.

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable definition
LOGFILE="/home/crash/deleted.log"
DATE=`date '+%d/%m/%Y'`
TIME=`date '+%T'`
FIND=`find /home/crash -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`

# Code execution
printf "\n$DATE-$TIME\n" >> "$LOGFILE"

for d in $FIND; do
  # Check if crash folders are older than 14 days and have been exported
  if [[ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $d) ))" -gt "1209600" ]] && [[ "$(getfattr -d --absolute-names -n user.exported --only-values $d)" == "1" ]]; then
    #echo "$d is older than 14 days and exported"
    "rm -rfv $d" >> "$LOGFILE"
  # Check if crash folders are older than 30 days and delete regardless
  elif [[ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $d) ))" -gt "1814400" ]] && [[ "$(getfattr -d --absolute-names -n user.exported $d)" == FALSE ]]; then
    #echo "$d is older than 30 days"
    "rm -rfv $d" >> "$LOGFILE"
  fi
done
```

The IF part is working fine and it deleted the folders with the attribute "user.exported=1" but the ELIF part does not seem to work, as I only get an output in my bash such as:

```
/home/crash/1234: user.exported: No such attribut
./crash_remove.sh: Line 20: rm -rfv /home/crash/1234: File or Directory not found
```

When I look into the crash folder after the script ran, the folder and its content is still there.

I definitely have an error in my script but cannot see it. Please could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"rm -rfv $d"` ? Remove the `"`. You want `rm -rfv "$d"`. `Check if crash folders are older than 14 days and have been exported` - don't use stat. `find` has all you want to do. like `find . -type d \( -mtime 14 -a -exec sh -c '[ "$(getfattr -d --absolute-names -n user.exported --only-values "$1")" = "1" ]' -- {} \; \) -exec echo rm -vrf {} \;`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So I would not even need the for loop with your example?

Comment: `File or Directory not found` - are you sure that is the error message? I think you should see "comamnd not found". Yes, `find` already iterates through all the directories.

Comment: BTW, every time you put `>>"$LOGFILE"` on a command, that's re-opening the logfile, then closing and flushing it when the scope of the redirection is left. More efficient to open it only once; for example, by putting `exec >>"$LOGFILE"` early in the script; then *everything* goes to the file, whether you explicitly redirect it or not. Or you can redirect for an entire loop by putting the `>>"$LOGFILE"` after the `done`.

Comment: And in addition to the links KamilCuk provided, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only quote the expansions, not the whole command.

Instead of:

```
"rm -rfv $d"
```

do:

```
rm -rfv "$d"
```

If you quote it all, bash tries to run a command named literally `rm<space>-rfv<space><expansion of d>`.

Do not use backticks `. Use `$(...)` instead. [Bash hackers wiki obsolete deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Do not `for i in $(cat)` or `var=$(...); for i in $var`. Use a `while IFS= read -r` loop. [How to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Instead of `if [[ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $d) ))" -gt "1814400" ]]` just do the comparison in the arithmetic expansion, like: `if (( ( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" $d) ) > 1814400 ))`.

I think you could just do it all in `find`, like::

```
find /home/crash -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d '(' \
    -mtime 14 \
    -exec sh -c '[ "$(getfattr -d --absolute-names -n user.exported --only-values "$1")" = "1" ]' -- {} \; \
    -exec echo rm -vrf {} + \
')' -o '(' \
    -mtime 30 \
    -exec sh -c '[ "$(getfattr -d --absolute-names -n user.exported "$1")" = FALSE ]' -- {} \; \
    -exec echo rm -vrf {} + \
')' >> "$LOGFILE"
```

Comment: I just thought of catching a possible stderr and add that to the logfile, would I just add that with anoher `-o` to the above `find` command before writing to the logfile?

Comment: Could probably use `-exec ... {} +` on the `rm`s, since we don't need individual per-file results there.

Comment: @C.Felix, could you be more explicit about what you mean? If you just want to add stderr to the logfile, put `2>&1` at the end, after the `>>"$LOGFILE"`

Comment: Redirect stderr to stdout. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Comment: Thanks for your help @KamilCuk - That is going to help me!